# TeamCity - using 2 svn folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, teamcity, visualsvn

I'm trying to build a project in TeamCity which contains some DLLs that the .csproj file is using, but I keep getting an error (CS0246) because they can't access the folder that they are in.

I added the 2 SVN (Subversion - VisualSVN) folders in my VCS roots, but do I need to edit in the .csproj file to edit the directory.. It's saving it in the format of "..\assemblies\" on the TeamCity server, but locally (when degbugging etc.) it's "....\common\assemblies"

Our other projects are using the DLLs so that's why they're in a single folder and not IN the project we're working on.

This is kinda hard to explain. I'll try and elaborate some more if it wasn't clear enough from the above.

```
<Reference Include="OpenCvSharp.MachineLearning">
  <HintPath>..\..\Common\assemblies\OpenCvSharp.MachineLearning.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Should be

```
<Reference Include="OpenCvSharp.MachineLearning">
  <HintPath>..\assemblies\OpenCvSharp.MachineLearning.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

To work properly on the teamcity server. However that is not an option because then we won't be able to debug locally etc. without having to change the path all the time.

"C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\fdbaf6ce1c990aa8\" then all the SVN folders are saved in there, which then leaves out the "main" folders of our projects and the folder that contains the DLLs

Anyone who knows how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [build configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kkz9kefa.aspx) to conditionally reference the same DLL, but on different paths. In the .csproj:

```
<Reference Include="OpenCvSharp.MachineLearning">
  <HintPath Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">..\..\Common\assemblies\OpenCvSharp.MachineLearning.dll</HintPath>
  <HintPath Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'TeamCity'">..\assemblies\OpenCvSharp.MachineLearning.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

You can add new build configurations in Visual Studio by right-clicking the solution file in **Solution Explorer** `->` **Configuration Manager...** then clicking the dropdown for **Active solution configuration:** and selecting **< New...>**:

[image: Adding the new TeamCity build configuration]

The downside is that you'll have to edit your .csproj files to include the above conditionals, though.

Comment: I will try this and report back after :)